# POST Connection from swift2 IOS to PHP

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am little bit confused with code which i have used to post parameters to php webservice. Is this code creates post connection or just used get connection. because of maximum character limit (2048 max characters) of url i have to use post connection between iphone app and php file. Is this code works for long data like all latitudes and longitudes between two locations (later on will need to send it on server). I have searched a lot but i am still confused. Please help me guyz.
Code:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: CommonUtils.webservice_path)!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "type=updateUserDetail&Fname=" + fName + "&Lname=" + lName + "&mobile=" + mobileNo + "&phoneCode=" + countryCode + "&user_id=" + iUserId_str!
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if(data==nil){

        }else{

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that code create a post method

the code i have used is below

> SWIFT 2.0

```
    let post:NSString = "Pram1=\(ratingUp)"

            NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

            let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://yoururltopost.com")! //change it to your url

            let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)! //data is being encoded

            let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

            let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST" //setting method as post
            request.HTTPBody = postData
            request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
            request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept") //set type of api
           // request.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") // use if you are use Authorization



            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){

                (data, response, error) -> Void in



                if (error == nil && data != nil)

                {

                    func parseJson()

                    {

                       // do whatever you want to do


                        }else{
// show error
                            let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                            alertView.title = "Rating Error"
                            alertView.message = "Please try after some time"
                            alertView.delegate = self
                            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                            alertView.show()

                        }


                    }



                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), parseJson)

                }
            }

            task.resume()
```

Comment: first line  "let post:NSString = "Pram1=\(ratingUp)"  contains all parameters that i want to pass to server . is this correct?

Comment: Yes "Pram1=value1&Pram2=value2"

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 way for POST method, depends on the API, one is single URL and your request body is an dictionary (eg "type":"updateUserDetail",..), second is append your `postString` to the URL with empty body, what u doing is put the string that suppose to append to URL to the request body and that probably wont work

Comment: for large data you create a pair of `key:object` then encode it with `NSData` (method based on API) then append it to the body, its different than make a string with `&`, its for URL, your way i don't think its correct for anything